# Cannot register SQL Reporting Service in SharePoint 2016

Tags: 2016, reporting-services

I am using SharePoint 2016 farm with min roles (Front End with Distributed cache and Application with Search). I am using SQL Server 2014 SP 2 on the database Server.

I ran below commands to register SQL Server Reporting Service and then opened the services on server in Central Administration to start SSRS service, I see "Sorry something went wrong" error with correlation id.

> Install-SPRSService
>   Install-SPRSServiceProxy

"Sorry something went wrong" error disappeared once I Uninstall the Service and proxy using below commands

> Install-SPRSService -Uninstall
>   Install-SPRSServiceProxy -Uninstall

I have installed Reporting Services features in both App Server and WFE Server using SQL Server 2014 SP2 Image file. I referred [Install SQL Server Reporting Services in multi server SharePoint 2013 farm with Windows 2012 R2 and SQL Server 2014 hosted in Azure VMs](http://dinushaonline.blogspot.in/2015/03/install-sql-server-reporting-services.html) article.

Prior to trying the reporting services features from image file I tried installing the features using the [Add-in](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53162) provided by microsoft. However that also resulted in the same error.

Please let me know if more details are required.

**Below are the error messages from the hive logs:**

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ServiceInstanceDataSourceView.FillDataTable(DataTable
>   table, DataSourceSelectArguments selectArguments)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DataTableDataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   selectArguments)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AdministrationDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments)      at
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
>   (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException'
>   was thrown. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ServiceInstanceDataSourceView.FillDataTable(DataTable
>   table, DataSourceSelectArguments selectArguments)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DataTableDataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   selectArguments)      at
>
> Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AdministrationDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments)      at
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
>   at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)      at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 1):

Only SSRS 2016 is supported for SharePoint 2016 Integraded Mode. If you cannot acquire a license for SSRS 2016, consider installing SSRS 2014 in Native Mode and using the SSRS Webparts to access the reports.

Comment: SQL Server is now upgraded to 2016 SP1. We are able to install SSRS Add-in in web front end server. But when we are installing "Reporting Services - SharePoint" in app server (custom roles), we are receiving below error.

Install-SPRSService : An update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this action. The object SPRSDiagnosticsService was updated by Farm Account, in the rsCustomAction (4156) process, on machine Front end server.

Comment: Flush the Config Cache on the servers and try again. An object may be stuck in there.

Comment: Flushed the config cache on both App and Front End Server and restarted them. I still see the same error. Any Idea?